# i cannot store moble number in mysql with node js

Tags: javascript, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLAoD.png)

add mobile number to MySQL db with using nodejs and express , i also trying but no help

Answer (score 0):

1. Add more `?` to `VALUES` (should be 4), line 50.
2. Change order in params according to `INSERT` statement (mobile should be after password hash, not before), line 51.
3. Check your table `users` has column `mobile`.